# Component variable not updating in subscription

Tags: angular

Using EventEmitter in Service for cross component communication.

When it emits event its calling subscription and printing expected data in the log. But when trying to update a property it's not doing it, also not getting any errors.

In debugging when i checked `this.selectedCategory` the value in subscription code I can see its updated, but when I see `selectedCategory = {} as ArtCategory;` it's showing

> "Cannot read property 'selectedCategory' of undefined"

How do I fix this?

**Event Emitter from Service**

```
export class GalleryService {
  categorySelected = new EventEmitter<ArtCategory>();
  catagories : ArtCategory[] = [];
  constructor() { }
}
```

**Event Triggered Code**

```
export class GalleryComponent implements OnInit {
  artCategories: ArtCategory[];

  constructor(private artCategoryService: ArtCategoryService, private galleryService: GalleryService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.artCategories = this.artCategoryService.categories;
  }

  showCategoryArts(artCategory: ArtCategory) {
    this.galleryService.categorySelected.emit(artCategory);
    this.router.navigate(['categoryArts']);
  }
}
```

**Event Subscription Code**

```
export class CategoryArtsComponent implements OnInit {

  selectedCategory = {} as ArtCategory;
  constructor(private artService : ArtsService, private galleryService : GalleryService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.galleryService.categorySelected.subscribe(
      (artCategory: ArtCategory) => {
          console.log(artCategory);
          this.selectedCategory = artCategory;
      });
  }
}
```

Comment: Side note: EventEmitters are not intended to be subscribed manually, but only through templates. If you want to subscribe yourself you should use the appropriate rxjs Subject.

Comment: Okay, Thanks for the suggestion. I have tried Subject also, Still its not updating.